# Test if any RCS-controlled files in tree are not checked in

Tags: version-control, rcs

I have multiple project trees of legacy code that are using RCS for version control with multiple users. I'd like to be able to walk the tree and test if any files are checked out (and thus the tree is not ready to be packaged for distribution update).

For example, I have a test tree:  `tree -p .`

```
.
├── [-r--r--r--]  file1
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  RCS
│   └── [-r--r--r--]  file1,v
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  subdir1
│   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  RCS
│   │   └── [-r--r--r--]  sfile1,v
│   └── [-rw-r--r--]  sfile1
└── [drwxrwxr-x]  subdir2
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  RCS
│   └── [-r--r--r--]  sfile2,v
└── [-r--r--r--]  sfile2

5 directories, 6 files
```

In which all files but `sfile1` are checked in to their respective RCS dirs. `sfile1` has been checked out and modified.

`rlog subdir1/sfile1` (a file that is properly checked-out) returns:

```
RCS file: subdir1/RCS/sfile1,v
Working file: subdir1/sfile1
head: 1.1
branch:
locks: strict
    torfey: 1.1
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 1; selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1    locked by: torfey;
date: 2016/07/20 13:09:34;  author: torfey;  state: Exp;
Initial revision
=============================================================================
```

Whereas `rlog subdir2/sfile2` (a file that is properly checked-in) returns:

```
RCS file: subdir2/RCS/sfile2,v
Working file: subdir2/sfile2
head: 1.1
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 1; selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2016/07/20 13:10:04;  author: torfey;  state: Exp;
Initial revision
=============================================================================
```

So the command I'd like would, given a directory argument, search for all files under that dir that are part of RCS and return names of any that are not checked in. (Ideally, also if there's some other state that is detectable and bad, like not locked yet different from checked in version, report that too.)

```
test_rcs_tree .
```

It would return, for my above simple case:

```
./subdir1/sfile1 checked-out
```

What I'm struggling with is whether there's maybe something out there that already does this that I'm just missing in all my searches.

I'm running on RHEL 6.7 which has rcs 5.7, gnu awk 3.1.7, gnu make 3.81, bash 4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a legacy rcs status script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ${@:-.} -type f |
sed '\;/RCS/;d' |
while read file
do  msg=
    if [ -z "$(rlog -R "$file" 2>/dev/null)" ]
    then    msg="$msg no RCS"
    else    if co -q -kk -p "$file" | cmp -s - "$file" ||
               co -q -p "$file" | cmp -s - "$file"
            then    msg="$msg same"
            else    msg="$msg differs"
            fi
            if [ -z "$(rlog -L -R "$file")" ]
            then    msg="$msg not locked"
            else    msg="$msg locked"
                    user=$(rlog -h "$file" |
                           awk '/locks:/{ getline;
                                    sub(":"," "); print $1 }')
                    if [ -n "$user" ]
                    then    msg="$msg by $user"
                    fi
            fi
    fi
    if [ -w "$file" ]
    then    msg="$msg writeable"
    fi
    echo "$file: $msg"
done
```

Give it a directory or files and it will produce output like

```
whenerror: same not locked
kshrc: same not locked writeable
mylua.lua: no RCS writeable
subshell: differs locked by meuh writeable
mshrc: differs locked by meuh
```

where "same not locked" means it is checked in, and read-only, normally the desired state.

Comment: Sweet!  That's exactly what I need. Worked great on my real tree.

Answer (score 1):

I use a utility [`checkup`](http://invisible-island.net/ded/manpage/checkup.html), which I wrote in the late 1980s, and pipe the results into my directory editor [`ded`](http://invisible-island.net/ded/), from which I can run `rcsdiff`, or unlock or revert changes.

For the sake of example, a screenshot showing some files which are not checked-in, as well as one newer than the last check-in date:

[image]